# Joomla - Remove script tags from head with a custom plugin

Tags: plugins, joomla, content-management-system, joomla4

I am making a content plugin that should do some changes on the website and load some scripts depending on the settings that the user made in the plugin.
The problem, where I need help, is how to get all tags inside  and do some changes and remove some  tags.
The  tags that I want to remove are added from a third party plugin (it should be installed, can't just remove it).

onContentPrepare() has $article but the  content is not there.
I couldn't find the scirpts that I want to remove with getWebAssetManager(), probably not even registered there.
onContentAfterDisplay() didn't help me and onBeforeCompileHead() same.
I can add scripts and styles, but can't get a list from all tags that are there when the page is completely loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event you are looking for is `onAfterRender()`, which is a system plugin.
You should add a system plugin, and invoke your code in the content plugin from there if you want to keep all the business logic in the content plugin.

In `onBeforeCompileHead()` you get a list of scripts, yet to be written to the html output, which is easy to manipulate; but it is possible for an extension developer to include tags and scripts in the view markup or by echoing them, and you wouldn't have those in the `document->_scripts` array.

In case the other plugin is also a system type, and in (unlikely) scenario it uses `onAfterRender()` to add its tags, you would only find the tags if your plugin is sorted *after* the offending plugin.

You can check out my toomanyfiles plugin [github repo](https://github.com/riczorn/toomanyfiles) ([JED page](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/too-many-files/)) - compatibility up to Joomla 4.0 only, I haven't tested it on later versions.  Its purpose is to heavily manipulate the header and specifically scripts and styles, compressing some, removing them, and adding the compressed version instead.

Be warned that the code is unnecessarily complex, ugly and convoluted; but you'll find all the relevant calls and logic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made a system plugin that should just remove the script that I don't want to be used.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work as it should be working.
I can see the scripts now here $doc->_scripts. I tried unset() for the one I don't need, I tried unset() to the whole array, I tried  $doc->_scripts = array(), but they are all added at the end.
With Factory::getDocument()->getHeadData() I still can't see the scripts I need to remove.
I also tried doing all this in onBeforeCompileHead() and onBeforeRender().
Not a single script is removed. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: definitely; if you unset the arrays and still the scripts injected, it means you're doing it too late (possibly in onAfterRender); feel free to use my code's approach (which manipulates the rendered page i.e. the html code that's generated)

Comment: I got it working, thanks one more time. onAfterRender() is where I got the whole html.
Instead of using getHeadData() I used Factory::getApplication()->getBody(), removed the script with preg_replace() and put the new string with setBody();